# Ensure two Python classes have properties of same name

Tags: python, class, oop, interface

I am looking towards building a class interface in Python but finds that Python lacks interface constructs.

What I need is that if a programmer tries to add new properties in one class without adding properties with the same name in another class, an exception to be raised (at compile time or run time)

An example:

```
class MongoCompany:
    company_name = MongoField()

class ESCompany:
    company_name = ESField()
```

an exception will be raised if a programmer tries to add a field to `MongoCompany` without changing `ESCompany`.

```
class MongoCompany:
    company_name = MongoField()
    company_phone = MongoField()

class ESCompany:
    company_name = ESField()

MongoCompany.init()
```

*Edit*:

**Background**
This is to prevent programmers from modifying MongoDB's schema declared with Mongoengine's `Document` class without adding the corresponding modification to Elasticsearch's schema declared in another file with elasticsearch-dsl's `DocType` class.

Comment: At first blush, are you familiar with the concept of [inheritance](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php)?

Comment: You could create an "interface" class that both inherit from with `throw NotImplementedError`s on the various methods required.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it doesn't prevent programmer from adding more attributes than the "interface" class has, to the subclasses.

Comment: You could have a quick runtime check at the very beginning of your program to compare the classes.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you mean some code that inspects two classes? no pythonic class constucts can be used?

Comment: Check out this concept of [freeze](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576527-freeze-make-any-object-immutable) I just found. I think you might be able to instantiate from a parent class and freeze the object in the child constructor. which might be what you want? I'm working out an example right now. 
Edit: maybe not but it's an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yay! An actual application of metaclasses that isn't contrived just for the sake of using metaclasses! We can write a metaclass which will throw if unexpected properties appear in a class definition. All we need to do is make sure your programmers actually use it.

```
class RequiredFieldsMeta(type):
    _interface = {'company_name', 'num_employees'}

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        for field in RequiredFieldsMeta._interface:
            if field not in attrs:
                raise AttributeError(
                   'Class %s missing required property %s'
                    % (clsname, field))
        for name in attrs:
            if not isdunder(name) and name not in RequiredFieldsMeta._interface:
                raise AttributeError(
                    'Class %s has extra property %s'
                    % (clsname, name))
        return super(RequiredFieldsMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)

# Works fine:
class MongoCompany(metaclass=RequiredFieldsMeta):
    company_name = 'Mongo Inc.'
    num_employees = 100

# Throws AttributeError:
class ESyCompany(metaclass=RequiredFieldsMeta):
    extra_prop = 'foobar'
```

[Here's](https://repl.it/JieY/1) a quick demo

Note how we don't even make it to instantiation: our check gets run when the class itself is defined.

EDIT: In my edit, I reference a function `is_dunder`. This can be as simple as `name.startswith('__')` or a regex or whatever you want, so long as it gets rid of properties that python, not the programmer, put on the class.

---

EDIT 2: Just for fun, here are two, more "elegant" (though less specific) implementations of our check:

```
def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
    attr_names = {a for a in attrs if not is_dunder(a)}

    if attr_names.difference(RequiredFieldsMeta._interface):
        raise AttributeError('Class %s has extra properties' % clsname)
    if RequiredFieldsMeta._interface.difference(attr_names):
        raise AttributeError('Class %s missing required properties' % clsname)

    return super(RequiredFieldsMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
```

Or simply:

```
def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
    attr_names = {a for a in attrs if not is_dunder(a)}
    if attr_names != RequiredFieldsMeta._interface:
        raise AttributeError(
            'Class %s does not match the required interface' % clsname)
    return super(RequiredFieldsMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
```

Comment: ah thanks, i think this is exactly what I need, however the code doesn't work as expected? MongoCompany throws an error. but I get the idea.

Comment: The syntax for using meta classes changed between python 2 & 3. Which version are you on?

Comment: I believe it's 3.6.1, I am running your quick demo. it's a typo num_employess, and there's something else.....

Comment: [this](https://repl.it/JieY/1) should do it. I just used `w.startswith('__')` as my "is dunder" predicate. You could use a regex or check `endswith` too if you want a stricter check